# How to add complex animation to splash screen with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm not good at animation but want to add animation which is like , there are 4 alphabets letters  "B", "C" , "D" and "E" which should animate from their 4 axis towards to the center and make a logo at center then when animation get complete, social buttons should animtate from the bottom that's all I want to implements.

I'm going to add screens which make my concept more clear, what I'm trying to say :

First view

[image]

second view

[image]

Code for simple for showing Splash image

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _SplashScreenState();
  }
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Timer? timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    navigatePage();
  }

  void navigatePage() async {
    timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
      isLoggedIn
          ? Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "home")
          : Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "login");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF7F8F8),
        body: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/splash.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `AnimatedPositioned` and `AnimatedRotation`:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool animated = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            animated = !animated;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedPositioned(
            top: animated
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .50
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .75,
            right: animated
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .100
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .50,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
              turns: animated ? 0.3 : 0.45,
              child: container(color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            top: animated
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .25
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .50,
            right: animated
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .25
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .50,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
              turns: animated ? 0.3 : 0.1,
              child: container(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            top: animated
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .75
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .15,
            right: animated
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .50
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .25,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
              turns: animated ? -0.3 : 0.13,
              child: container(color: Colors.yellow),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget container({Color color = Colors.grey}) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks to you , I got idea from your code and added some more efforts and it made my day.

Answer (score 0):

I created the animation simply using `Hero`, focused on the animation is BETWEEN PAGES.

Please refer to the example for not wearing fancy colours or designs.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _SplashScreenState();
  }
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageRouteBuilder(
            transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const LoginPage(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffF7F8F8),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(child: MainLogoItem()),
            Positioned(
              top: 150,
              child: LogoItem('B'),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 50,
              left: 30,
              child: LogoItem('C'),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 20,
              bottom: 130,
              child: LogoItem('D'),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 30,
              right: 70,
              child: LogoItem('E'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: const Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffF7F8F8),
        body: Center(child: Logo()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Logo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Logo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey,
            blurRadius: 5,
            spreadRadius: 1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: const Stack(
        children: [
          Align(child: MainLogoItem()),
          Positioned(
            left: 20,
            top: 10,
            child: LogoItem('B'),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 10,
            left: 15,
            child: LogoItem('C'),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            child: LogoItem('D'),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: -10,
            right: 30,
            child: LogoItem('E'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainLogoItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainLogoItem({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const LogoItem('A', fontSize: 50);
  }
}

class LogoItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String alphabet;
  final double? fontSize;

  const LogoItem(
    this.alphabet, {
    super.key,
    this.fontSize,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: 'LogoItem $alphabet',
      child: Text(
        alphabet,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          fontSize: fontSize ?? 30,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          height: 0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## How to test

1. Paste & copy the codes.
2. Add `SplashScreen` to your app.
3. Tap screen then it navigate you to `LoginPage` with animation.
4. Tap again to get back to `SpalshScreen`.

I did my best but I am pretty sure there must be a better solution.

I hope you get some hints from my code though.

Comment: I appreciate for giving your time . but I made it with some efforts.

Comment: Good to hear that! I have learn from your solution there. Enjoy your code ;D

Answer (score 0):

After adding lots of efforts finally I achieved this.

[image: Output_video]

Splash Screen :

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  bool animated = false;
  bool animationDone = false;
  int animationDuration = 2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      _startAnimationAndNavigate();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  _startAnimationAndNavigate() {
    setState(() {
      animated = !animated;
    });
    Timer(Duration(seconds: animationDuration), () async {
      setState(() {
        animationDone = true;
      });
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageRouteBuilder(
            transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                const LoginScreen(),
          ),
        );
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Hero(
              tag: "MyAnimation",
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                  height: animationDone ? 140 : null,
                  width: animationDone ? 140 : null,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: animationDone ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
                      borderRadius:
                          animationDone ? BorderRadius.circular(30) : null,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 11.0,
                          color: animationDone
                              ? Colors.black12
                              : Colors.transparent,
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: ParentLogo()),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            bottom: animated ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.4 : 50,
            left: animated ? 140 : 30,
            duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
              turns: animated ? -0.1 : 0.45,
              child: Letter("C", animationDone: animationDone),

            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            bottom: animated ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.4 : 50,
            right: animated ? 150 : 30,
            duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
              turns: animated ? 0.1 : 0.1,
              child: Letter("D", animationDone: animationDone),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            top: animated
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.25
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
            left: animated ? 140 : 30,
            duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
              turns: animated ? -0.1 : -0.1,
              // turns: animated ? -0.3 : 0.13,
              child: Letter("B", animationDone: animationDone),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            top: animated ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.47 : 10,
            right: animated ? 150 : 30,
            duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: Duration(seconds: animationDuration),
              turns: animated ? -0.1 : 0.2,
              child: Letter("E", animationDone: animationDone),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Login Screen :

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    animationController.forward();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Expanded(
              child:
                  Center(child: Hero(tag: 'MyAnimation', child: CustomLogo())),
            ),
            loginView(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  loginView() {
    return SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(0, 1), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(animationController),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const TextWidget(
                text: "Sign in to Connect!",
                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: 22,
              ),
              const TextWidget(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                text:
                    "Sign in and experience the ultimate tool for goal\nachievers!",
                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              _socialButtonView(
                asset: "assets/images/google_icon.png",
                title: "Log in with Google",
                onTap: () {},
                bgColor: MyColor.whiteColor,
                foregroundColor: MyColor.blackColor,
              ),
              _socialButtonView(
                asset: "assets/images/apple_icon.png",
                title: "Log in with Apple",
                onTap: () {},
                bgColor: MyColor.blackColor2,
                foregroundColor: MyColor.whiteColor,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  _socialButtonView(
      {required String title,
      required String asset,
      required Color bgColor,
      required Color foregroundColor,
      required void Function()? onTap}) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        height: 54,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: bgColor,
          //  MyColor.blackColor2,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          border: Border.all(width: 1, color: MyColor.blackColor2),
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              asset,
              height: 26,
              width: 26,
            ),
            TextWidget(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              textColor: foregroundColor,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
              text: title,
              fontSize: 17,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Center logo / Parent logo

```
class ParentLogo extends StatelessWidget {
  const ParentLogo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.asset(
      "assets/images/whatsa.png",
      height: 63,
      width: 63,
    );
  }
}
```

Custom logo :

```
class CustomLogo extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomLogo({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 140,
      height: 140,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          boxShadow: const [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 11.0,
              color: Colors.black12,
            )
          ]),
      child: const Stack(
        children: [
          Align(child: ParentLogo()),
          Positioned(
            left: 20,
            top: 10,
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              turns: -0.1,
              child: Letter("B",),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 10,
            left: 15,
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              turns: -0.1,
              child: Letter("C", ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              turns: 0.1,
              child: Letter("D", ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: -10,
            right: 30,
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              turns: -0.1,
              child: Letter("E",),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Letter view :

```
class Letter extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool animationDone;
  final String l;
  const Letter(this.l, {super.key, this.animationDone = true});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      style: TextStyle(
        color: getItemColor(l),
        fontSize: animationDone
            ? l == "B" || l == "D"
                ? 40
                : 50
            : l == "B" || l == "D"
                ? 70
                : 80,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      child: Text(
        l,
      ),
    );
  }

  Color getItemColor(String l) {
    switch (l) {
      case "B":
        return const Color(0xFFFFEBD7);
      case "C":
        return const Color(0xFFDFF4E7);
      case "D":
        return const Color(0xFFE4EAF4);
      case "E":
        return const Color(0xFFE0DEDF);
      default:
        return Colors.black;
    }
  }
}
```